# How to understand these functions?

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following exercise to solve: Let $f,g: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous at $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and let $h,k : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as:

$$h(x)=\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n}\{f(x),g(x)\} \quad\quad k(x)=\inf_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n}\{f(x),g(x)\}$$

show that $h$ and $k$ are continuous at $a$.

Now, my problem is not on showing continuity, my problem is that I'm not really understanding those functions. If I understood well $h$ is for instance $h(x)=\sup\{f(x),g(x) : x \in \mathbb{R}^n\}$, so in my understanding, $h$ returns the greater between $f$ and $g$, but the problem is that the argument being passes is allowed to vary over $\mathbb{R}^n$. The problem I see with this is that $h(x)$ is what I've said, we allow $x$ to run all over $\mathbb{R}^n$, we get a set of real numbers and get the supremum.

On the other hand, the only reasonable thing I could imagine this would be is that for each point we compare $f$ and $g$ and return the supremum, so that for $(0,1) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ it would be $h(0,1) = \sup\{f(0,1),g(0,1)\}$, but I can't see why I would use this, since a set with finite reals always has maximum and minimum.

Can someone just tell me how to understand these functions $h$ and $k$?

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definitions you display make little sense, because the index in $\sup\limits_{x\in \mathbb R^n}\{\cdots\}$ *binds* the variable $x$ so it is no longer a free variable of the expression. Therefore, as given the two definitions define *constant* functions $h$ and $k$, and constant functions are of course continuous everywhere, and in particular at $a$.

But it seems strange that this could be what is meant. It is more likely that there is a typo either in the exercise or in your transcription of it.

I would guess what is actually meant is simply $h(x)=\max(f(x),g(x))$, and similarly for the minimum.

Comment: Thanks for the help @HenningMakhlom, it wasn't a typo in the transcript really, I've transcripted exactly as it is in the exercise. I thought the same as you've said. There's probably something wrong with the exercise then. Anyway, thanks for your help! I'll do using the mininum and the maximum.